# Why is my constructor not working in the UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, constructor

Hopefully I am framing this question right, but I cannot figure out why my code is not working correctly.

I have essentially made a simple application for ordering pizza using objects and constructors in Javascript. I've created my Pizza object that stores various toppings as well as created a constructor with conditionals that are supposed to change the price of the pizza based off of the size selected.

All of that seems to be in order, but when I try to put the new Pizza constructor in the UI, when the user hits submit the calculated price will not show up. I've Googled and tried watching tutorial videos for hours. Not sure what I am missing here.

If someone could help, that would be great. I am new to javascript and struggle quite a bit with it. Thank you.

Here is my scripts page:

```
function Pizza(veggie, meat, cheese, sauce, size) {
  this.veggie = veggie;
  this.meat = meat;
  this.cheese = cheese;
  this.sauce = sauce;
  this.size = size;
  this.pizzaPrice = 0;
  this.amount = amount;
}

Pizza.prototype.pizzaCost = function () {
  if (this.size === "small") {
    this.pizzaPrice === 10.00
  } else if (this.size == "Medium") {
    this.pizzaPrice == 12.00
  } else if (this.size == "Large") {
    this.pizzaPrice === 13.00
  } else if (this.size === "Mega") {
    this.pizzaPrice === 14.50
    return Pizza.prototype.pizzaCost(); 
}

//UI//

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#formOne").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const veggie = $("select#veggies").val();
    const meat = $("select#meat'").val();
    const cheese = $("select#cheese").val();
    const sauce = $("select#sauce").val();
    const size = $("select#size").val();

//Here is where I am having no luck... the ID tags match in the html so I know that isn't the issue either

    let newPizza = new Pizza (veggie + meat + cheese + sauce + size + Pizza.prototype.pizzaCost())
    $("#result").append("<text>" + "$" + newPizza + "</text>");
  })})}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

- Correct the braces syntax. Current the jQuery document.ready handler is inside the `pizzaCost()` function.
- In the `pizzaCost()` function you need to:

  - Move the `return` statement *outside* the `if` statement
  - Return a value, not just set a property of the class
  - Correct the mistaken use of `==` and `===` to set a value. Those operators are for *comparison* only.
- Fix the syntax where you call the constructor. You seem to be using the `+` operator to separate your arguments. It should be `,` instead.
- Remove the `pizzaCost()` argument from the constructor call. You've not defined it in the constructor itself.
- The `<text>` element is for use in SVG graphics. It's not relevant to this HTML and should be removed.
- Use `text()` and not `append()` to avoid duplicating content on repeated form submissions.

With all that corrected, the code works like this:

```js
function Pizza(veggie, meat, cheese, sauce, size) {
  this.veggie = veggie;
  this.meat = meat;
  this.cheese = cheese;
  this.sauce = sauce;
  this.size = size;
  this.pizzaPrice = 0;
}

Pizza.prototype.pizzaCost = function() {
  if (this.size === "small") {
    this.pizzaPrice = 10.00
  } else if (this.size === "Medium") {
    this.pizzaPrice = 12.00
  } else if (this.size === "Large") {
    this.pizzaPrice = 13.00
  } else if (this.size === "Mega") {
    this.pizzaPrice = 14.50
  }
  return this.pizzaPrice;
}

jQuery($ => {
  $("#formOne").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const veggie = $("select#veggies").val();
    const meat = $("select#meat").val();
    const cheese = $("select#cheese").val();
    const sauce = $("select#sauce").val();
    const size = $("select#size").val();

    let newPizza = new Pizza(veggie, meat, cheese, sauce, size);
    $("#result").text("$" + newPizza.pizzaCost());
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formOne">
  <select id="veggies">
    <option>Tomato</option>
  </select>
  <select id="meat">
    <option>Pepperoni</option>
  </select>
  <select id="cheese">
    <option>Mozzarella</option>
  </select>
  <select id="sauce">
    <option>Passata</option>
  </select>
  <select id="size">
    <option>small</option>
    <option>Medium</option>
    <option>Large</option>
    <option>Mega</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

As a side note, your pattern of setting the `pizzaPrice` property in `pizzaCost()` is a little odd. Normally you'd either return a separate value from the function, or update that property based on the changing properties of the class as they get updated. This is because until the `pizzaCost()` function is called the price will be `0`, even though properties may have been set which affect the price.

Comment: Wow, ok I see. Thank you! My only further question is that I have never seen jQuery($ => used in place of $(document).ready. What is the difference? Thank you for your help.

Comment: There's no difference, `jQuery($ => {})` is just using ES6 syntax - and no problem, glad to help :)